# React-native QR code scanner is throwing error

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have a react-native app where I have developed a scanner feature using  react-native-qrcode-scanner.However, when I try to scan the data, I get the below error-

```
error: can't find variable navigation
```

I see this error in onSuccess method at line authorizationToken. 
My code-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Text,
    View,
    Image,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Linking
} from 'react-native';
import styles from '../assets/style';
import QRCodeScanner from 'react-native-qrcode-scanner';

export default class ScanScreen extends Component {

    onSuccess(scanEvent) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Result", {
            'accessKey': scanEvent.data,
            'authorizationToken':navigation.getParam('authorizationToken', undefined), 
            "userData": navigation.getParam('userData', undefined),
            "methodName": "fetchData"
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <QRCodeScanner
                    onRead={this.onSuccess.bind(this)}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Any idea what I m missing here. Any help is much appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the line `'authorizationToken':navigation.getParam('authorizationToken', undefined),` where are you getting **navigation** from? It doesn't seem to be defined anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that Your Screen is registered in react-navigation config (follow this guide: can't find variable navigation).

Or pass navigation prop to it with HOC `withNavigation`: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html. Instead `export default class ScanScreen extends Component` do `class ScanScreen extends Component` and at end of file do

```
export default withNavigation(ScanScreen);
```

Don't forget about importing Higher Order Component: `import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';`

Also be sure that all native parts are properly linked. For example `react-native-gesture-handle` (https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/getting-started.html#linking).

Comment: It works fine in Android though so why does it create issue only in iOS.

Comment: I don't see information that iOS specific in your question. In that case answer will be `react-native link react-native-gesture-handler`

Comment: So, do I need  to delete node_modules, install this and link react-native link react-native-gesture-handler

Comment: react-native-gesture-handler linking is required for ios. Before that commit your code so link will not break your android app. and imo removing node_modules is not needed - as you have already all dependencies.

Comment: I cross checked and I am seeing this issue in both android and ios. So I have tried to to import HOC but I am still seeing the same error.

Comment: I had to add this.props.navigation and it works ! Thank you for your support though. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

navigation has to be part of props so accessing navigation using this.props.navigation solves this issue.